# getting 400 bad request on angular post request how can i fix this

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

please i need help on my angular and django project and i'm getting a 400 bad response error when i make a post request,the project work flow is as follows, the user signup(which is successful) then get redirected to a profile form then when i try making a post request after filling the profile i get a 400 err, below is my code and d err response

### angular services.ts

```
    addProfile(profile: Iprofile): Observable<Iprofile>{
        const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/profiles';
        return this.httpClient.post<Iprofile>(url, profile)
            .pipe(
                 map(response => response),
                 catchError(this.handleError)
            );
    }
```

### create profile component.ts

```
    addUpdateProfile(){
    if (this.profile) {
        this.dataService.updateProfile(this.profileForm.value)
        .subscribe(item => this.profiles.push(this.profileForm.value));
    }
    else {
        this.dataService.addProfile(this.profileForm.value)
        .subscribe(item => this.profiles.push(this.profileForm.value));
    }
  }
```

### django urls

```
path('profiles', CreateProfileView.as_view(), name='user-profile'),
```

### django views

```
class CreateProfileView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
queryset = Profile.objects.all()
serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer
```

### err response

Bad Request: /user/profiles
[14/May/2020 17:07:04] "POST /user/profiles HTTP/1.1" 400 46

will b glad if anyone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth saying for me I was getting a 400 error as my allowed hosts in my DJANGO settings were incorrect. It caught me out as I'd of thought I'd get a 403 rather than a 400 for something like this.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['yourhost.com']
```

Also don't be a doughnut like me and include `HTTP://` in your host string.

Answer (score 1):

In [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createmodelmixin), it refers that "If the request data provided for creating the object was invalid, a 400 Bad Request response will be returned, with the error details as the body of the response." so, the profile you have sent is invalid. To see which part is wrong, please log body or you can override and debug post method of [CreateApiView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview)